# How do waveguide displays stay in focus?

Tags: optics, lenses, waveguide

In VR headsets, because the displays are so close to the user's eyes, manufacturers need to add corrective optics so that the image is in focus. However, in AR glasses utilizing waveguide technologies such as the magic leap or hololens, there is no lens in front of the user's eyes even though the screens are the same distance away.

How are the images created by waveguides in focus, while VR headsets need corrective lenses? Or is there a fundamental difference between the display technologies that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The question is overly broad, because different AR/VR headsets use very different optics.  The bottom line, though, is that any AR or VR headset forms a virtual image at a large distance from the eye.  The user's eyes do not need to focus on the optical elements themselves (i.e., the lenses, the projection screen, etc.)

Comment: @S.McGrew I know that both the Magic Leap and Hololens use a type of waveguide technology, while VR headsets use a head-mounted display and lenses. I know this. I was wondering how the optics worked on AR waveguide displays.

Comment: Ah so.  That is a different question which I'll be glad to answer.  Can you edit your question to be specifically focused on waveguide displays?